# When I run application by installer, I am getting error as "Bad method token. "

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, obfuscation, token

I am working on C# Windows form application. When I run my application through the code everything works fine. I am creating the installer of the application. I am obfuscating the EXE.  But when I installed the installer and run the application I am getting error as:

> "Bad method token."  Stack Strace : at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.PrepareDelegate(Delegate
>   d)    at
>   System.AppDomain.add_UnhandledException(UnhandledExceptionEventHandler
>   value)    at
>   JB80W1Fe10kqFU9DUbJ.irnkUeFZDYQQy76X09T..ctor(ExportFilterOptions  ,
>   Boolean  )

Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This type of error is often related to obfuscation problems, especially if you are calling a method in a .dll through `InvokeMember`.  Things to try:

1. As a test, don't obfuscate and see if that fixes the problem.  If so, you will know it is obfuscator-related.
2. Try a different obfuscator.  Their quality varies pretty greatly, especially the 'community' and 'free' ones.  Get a good commercial obfuscator for production builds.
3. As a test, try without the installer.  Sometimes installers put files in unexpected places which can lead to runtime errors.  Make sure your files are all being installed in the directories you intend.
4. Make sure all your method parameters match in number and type if you are doing any `InvokeMember` calls.  If they do not match, a runtime error will result in code that the compiler had no way of validating.